# Biased Random Walk with Variable Probability

Tags: probability, random-walk

Consider a random walk in which the probability to move forward in time $t$ is $p_t$ and the probability to move backward is $q_t=1-p_t$ with $p_t<q_t$ with $p_t<p_{t+1}$ and $q_t>q_{t+1}$.

Moving forward will be by $f_t$ steps and moving backward by $b_t$ steps with $f_t>b_t$ but $f_{t+1}<f_t$ and $b_{t+1}>b_t$.

> For example,
>
> $p_1=0.4$, $q_1=0.6$, $f_1=10$,$b_1=5$.
>
> $p_2=0.45$, $q_2=0.55$, $f_2=8$,$b_2=6$.

and so on,

At time $t=n$, $p_n=0.5$ and $q_n=0.5$ with $f_n=1$ and $b_n=1$.

> The question is, is this random walk moving forward or backward, and if forward, what is the expected numbers of steps to move forward at time $t=n$?

Comment: Please note that if $p_t<p_{t+1}$ then $q_t>q_{t+1}$, and not as you wrote. Also, it seems you got the inequality $b_{t+1}<b_t$ reversed, too. I suppose the forward moves are a decreasing function of time with increasing probability and the backward moves an increasing function of time with (necessarily) decreasing probability. This is what seems to emerge from your numerical examples.

Comment: Sorry, but $b_1=5$, $b_2=6$ and $b_{t+1}<b_t$ are contradictory.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have changed the question.